# listings: move commas to the left with columns=flexible

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, listings, lstlisting

Compiling the code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[columns=flexible,mathescape,identifierstyle=\slshape,keywords={SPEC,sort},numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny,numbersep=5pt]
SPEC SomeSpecification =
{
  sort Sort1, AnotherSort, ThisOneIsOk, AFourthSort

  fun1:        Sort1 $\to$ AnotherSort
  anotherFun:  AnotherSort $\to$ AFourthSort
  thirdFun:    AnotherSort, AFourthSort $\to$ ThisOneIsOk
}
\end{document}
```

with pdflatex produces the output

[image: output]

As you see, in line 3 there is much more space between "AnotherSort" and the following comma than between "ThisOneIsOk" and the following comma. This might seem a minor issue, but the more sorts you have in line 3, the worse it looks. How to automatically "glue" the commas to their preceding words while keeping the alignments in

- lines 3 till 7, i.e., the first words ("sort", "fun1", "anotherFun", and "thirdFun") should start in the same column, and in
- lines 5 till 7, i.e., the function types after the colons ("Sort1", "AnotherSort", "AnotherSort") should start in the same column

?

I don't want to change the code between `\begin{lstlisting}[...]` and `\end{lstlisting}` much and would prefer a central solution (e.g., by some package option, some environment option, or some macro). I'm also very unlikely to switch to a monospaced font: it consumes more space.

Answer (score 1):

From the manual of `listings`:

> The difference between the three formats is that the full flexible format cares about nothing else, while the normal flexible and space-flexible formats try to fix the column alignment if a character string needs less space than ‘reserved’. The normal flexible format will insert make-up space to fix the alignment at spaces, before and after identifiers, and before and after sequences of other characters; the space-flexible format will only insert make-up space by stretching existing spaces. In the flexible example above, the two MENs are vertically aligned since some space has been inserted in the fourth line to fix the alignment. In the full flexible format, the two MENs are not aligned.

Here's the example

[image]

From the description, `flexible` is doing what it is meant to. Use `fullflexible` under any circumstances, particularly with a variable width font where doing column alignment doesn't make sense.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[
  columns=fullflexible,
  mathescape,
  identifierstyle=\slshape,
  keywords={SPEC,sort},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,numbersep=5pt]
SPEC SomeSpecification =
{
  sort Sort1, AnotherSort, ThisOneIsOk, AFourthSort

  fun1:        Sort1 $\to$ AnotherSort
  anotherFun:  AnotherSort $\to$ AFourthSort
  thirdFun:    AnotherSort, AFourthSort $\to$ ThisOneIsOk
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to keep alignment and not having “shifted punctuation”, use a monospaced font; there are several to choose from.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=flexible,
  basewidth={0.5em,0.5em},
  mathescape,
  identifierstyle=\slshape,
  keywords={SPEC,sort},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,numbersep=5pt]
SPEC SomeSpecification =
{
  sort Sort1, AnotherSort, ThisOneIsOk, AFourthSort

  fun1:        Sort1 $\to$ AnotherSort
  anotherFun:  AnotherSort $\to$ AFourthSort
  thirdFun:    AnotherSort, AFourthSort $\to$ ThisOneIsOk
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here the result with `\usepackage{sourcecodepro}`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but the types in the lines 5 till 7 (the stuff after the colon ":") in your example are not aligned as they should be.

Comment: @PaulStanley I think the image in my question makes it perfectly clear how the types after the colons should be aligned. I've even added an explanation.

Comment: @VasiliPupkin The space is not added in front of the comma or the colon, but after the block of characters that precede them. This might seem the same, but it isn't: when `listings` comes to the comma, it has already added the space.

Comment: Thank you, the monospaced variants are all great except that they are too wide; the text that fitted previously into one line won't fit any more. This forces you to user smaller font sizes and the like, which reduced the readability. In my text, switching to monospace would be considered inferior to wrongly placed commas.